# What is the formula for finding the number of ways that can be combined to give a selected sum?

Tags: combinations

Suppose that I have several boards.  Four of them are 2 inches long, three of them are 3 inches long. How many ways are there to combine them to make 11 inches?  Or to make 7 inches? I need the formula that allows me to enter the lengths of various boards, the number of each size, and the total length of the combination.

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange! This looks like an interesting question, but this site has some standards which your question appears to not satisfy; i.e. Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress (**what have you tried so far?**), why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Say the total length is $n$, that $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_i,\dots$ are sizes of available boards and that $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_i,\dots$ are the amounts of available boards. Are you asking what is the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ such that summand $x_i$ appears at most $t_i$ times, for the given sets of boards?

Comment: Do you consider the boards to be the same? For example, for the question "how many ways are there to make a combination of length 2 inches", is the answer 1 or 4?

Comment: In general, this looks like finding the number of integer solutions to
$$
2x_1 + 3x_2 = n
$$
with some limitations on how large $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be .